# How to unblock a website in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, connection

I am using Win 10 (64-bit). I ran a program that's supposed block Windows 10 'spying'. As a result, it did something, and now I can't visit several websites. When I try to visit them, I get this error:

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My computer is not infected with malware. The `hosts` file is clean. No firewall/router is blocking connection. I had disabled the AV/Firewall and tried. No luck!

No browser extension is also blocking access. No adblocking software/plugins. My ISP is also not blocking, since these websites are accessible on my mobile via WiFi. Running the Windows Troubleshooter did not help.

When pinged in the CMD, I found that the name is being resolved to `127.0.0.1`. No, I can't "System Restore". I still get this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What program exactly did you run to block win10 'spying'?

Comment: Why can't you "System Restore"? What happened when you tried? Did you get an error?

Comment: What is your DNS set to?

Comment: Try a proxy like ultrasurf and see if it works after that

Comment: If a any website is being redirect to 127.0.0.0 then that is your hosts file.  Why can't you use the same software to reverse the process?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I ran "Destroy Windows 10 Spying" program. I've deleted my Windows Restore points to gain disk space!.
@ bertieb Thank you so much. Set my DNS to Google DNS and it worked. Looks like my ISP is blocking, But however, all sites work fine on my mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I ran "Destroy Windows 10 Spying" program.

Destroy Windows 10 Spying is a portable app so you should be just able to delete it.

However:

- It modifies the host file.
- It removes a bunch of apps (I've no idea what these are).
- "[IObit Uninstaller](http://www.iobit.com/en/advanceduninstaller.php) also spotted Destroy Windows 10 Spying running and removed leftover entries from the uninstall."

It looks like you need to:

- Edit your host file and remove any unwanted entries.
- Run an unistaller to clean up any leftovers.

> Destroy Windows 10 Spying is a portable app that can block anonymous data being sent, remove apps that can’t be removed the standard way and more.

...

> I took a huge chance and ran this on my clean Windows 10 installation. It did modify the hosts file exactly as promised and did remove the Apps it promised. IObit Uninstaller also spotted Destroy Windows 10 Spying running and removed leftover entries from the uninstall.

Source [Destroy Windows 10 Spying 1.5 Build 450](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/destroy_windows_10_spying.html)